# Check on field with BaseController

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `app.blade.php` file which I am applying to all existing pages using `@extends('layouts.app')`

In this file I have a data output with a variable

```
{!! $headerData !!}
```

This variable itself is located in the `Controller`, and is used for all controllers.

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{

    public function __construct(Request $request) 
    {
        View::share('headerData', HeaderData::getData($request));
    }

    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

But it turns out that it is declared only for those pages that have controllers, and for example I have a `404 error` page that does not have a controller and when I go to it I get an error

> Undefined variable: headerData

How can I check this `$headerData` variable in my `app.blade.php` file ?

Comment: When you say *how can I check* are you asking how to make sure it's set before using it?

Comment: @BrianThompson I mean how not to use this variable on pages where there are no controllers

Comment: I don't use blade often, but wouldn't it just be as simple as `{{!! isset($headerData) ? $headerData : '' !!}` or something similar?

Comment: There is an isset directive in Laravel which can be used here as Brian mentioned. See here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements